# Using Yii2 stack trace to troubleshoot

Tags: php, stack-trace, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to use the Yii2 stack trace to diagnose problems. Specifically, I can rarely find the source of the problem (in my code) based on what the trace tells me. I'm sure it's just me being obtuse, so I'm hoping someone can help me on this. As an example, I'm suddenly confronted with a "PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException
call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'error' not found" error, and I get the trace found below. I can't find anything in the trace listing that points me to what I may have done wrong in my coding. Everything seems to point to the core coding rather than mine. Can anyone help me here?

```
 PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException
```

call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'error' not found

```
1. in L:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php at line 346
337338339340341342343344345346347348349350351352353354355

    public static function createObject($type, array $params = [])
    {
        if (is_string($type)) {
            return static::$container->get($type, $params);
        } elseif (is_array($type) && isset($type['class'])) {
            $class = $type['class'];
            unset($type['class']);
            return static::$container->get($class, $params, $type);
        } elseif (is_callable($type, true)) {
            return call_user_func($type, $params);
        } elseif (is_array($type)) {
            throw new InvalidConfigException('Object configuration must be an array containing a "class" element.');
        } else {
            throw new InvalidConfigException("Unsupported configuration type: " . gettype($type));
        }
    }

    private static $_logger;


2. yii\base\ErrorHandler::handleError(2, 'call_user_func() expects paramet...', 'L:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\vend...', 346, ...)
3. in L:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php – call_user_func(['error', 'warning'], []) at line 346
4. in L:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\log\Dispatcher.php – yii\BaseYii::createObject(['error', 'warning']) at line 101
5. in L:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Object.php – yii\log\Dispatcher::init() at line 107
6. in L:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\log\Dispatcher.php – yii\base\Object::__construct(['traceLevel' => 3, 'targets' => ['class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget', 'levels' => ['error', 'warning']]]) at line 89
7. yii\log\Dispatcher::__construct(['traceLevel' => 3, 'targets' => ['class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget', 'levels' => ['error', 'warning']]])
8. in L:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php – ReflectionClass::newInstanceArgs([['traceLevel' => 3, 'targets' => ['class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget', 'levels' => ['error', 'warning']]]]) at line 368
9. in L:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php – yii\di\Container::build('yii\log\Dispatcher', [], ['traceLevel' => 3, 'targets' => ['class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget', 'levels' => ['error', 'warning']]]) at line 147
10. in L:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php – yii\di\Container::get('yii\log\Dispatcher', [], ['traceLevel' => 3, 'targets' => ['class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget', 'levels' => ['error', 'warning']]]) at line 344
11. in L:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\ServiceLocator.php – yii\BaseYii::createObject(['traceLevel' => 3, 'targets' => ['class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget', 'levels' => ['error', 'warning']], 'class' => 'yii\log\Dispatcher']) at line 133
12. in L:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php – yii\di\ServiceLocator::get('log') at line 302
13. in L:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php – yii\base\Application::bootstrap() at line 63
14. in L:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php – yii\web\Application::bootstrap() at line 267
15. in L:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Object.php – yii\base\Application::init() at line 107
16. in L:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php – yii\base\Object::__construct(['components' => ['cache' => ['class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache'], 'urlManager' => ['enablePrettyUrl' => true, 'showScriptName' => 'false', 'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager', 'rules' => ['<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view', '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>', '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>']], 'db' => ['class' => 'yii\db\Connection', 'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=larr...', 'username' => 'xxxx', 'password' => 'xxxx', ...], 'mailer' => ['class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer', 'viewPath' => '@common/mail', 'useFileTransport' => true], ...], 'modules' => ['social' => ['class' => 'kartik\social\Module', 'disqus' => ['settings' => ['shortname' => 'DISQUS_SHORTNAME']], 'facebook' => ['appId' => 'xxxxx', 'secret' => 'xxxxx']], 'gridview' => ['class' => '\kartik\grid\Module'], 'debug' => 'yii\debug\Module', 'gii' => 'yii\gii\Module'], 'id' => 'app-frontend', 'name' => 'MemeHope', ...]) at line 206
17. in L:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\frontend\web\index.php – yii\base\Application::__construct(['vendorPath' => 'L:\xampp\htdocs\public_html/vend...', 'components' => ['cache' => ['class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache'], 'urlManager' => ['enablePrettyUrl' => true, 'showScriptName' => 'false', 'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager', 'rules' => ['<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view', '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>', '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>']], 'db' => ['class' => 'yii\db\Connection', 'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=larr...', 'username' => 'xxxxx', 'password' => 'xxxxx', ...], 'mailer' => ['class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer', 'viewPath' => '@common/mail', 'useFileTransport' => true], ...], 'modules' => ['social' => ['class' => 'kartik\social\Module', 'disqus' => ['settings' => ['shortname' => 'DISQUS_SHORTNAME']], 'facebook' => ['appId' => 'xxxxxx', 'secret' => 'xxxx']], 'gridview' => ['class' => '\kartik\grid\Module'], 'debug' => 'yii\debug\Module', 'gii' => 'yii\gii\Module'], 'id' => 'app-frontend', ...]) at line 17
1112131415161718

    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../config/main-local.php')
);

$application = new yii\web\Application($config);
$application->run();
```

This is what frontend/config/main.php looks like:

```
<?php

$params = array_merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'), require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
);

return [
    'id'                  => 'app-frontend',
    'basePath'            => dirname(__DIR__),
    'name'                => 'MemeHope',
    'bootstrap'           => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'frontend\controllers',
    'components'          => [

        'urlManager'   => [
            'class'           => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName'  => 'false',
            'rules'           => [
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'              => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'          => '<controller>/<action>',
            ],
        ],
        'log'          => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets'    => [
                'class'  => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
            ],
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'user'         => [
            'identityClass'   => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
    ],
    'modules'             => [
        'gridview' => [
            'class' => '\kartik\grid\Module'
            // enter optional module parameters below - only if you need to
            // use your own export download action or custom translation
            // message source
            // 'downloadAction' => 'gridview/export/download',
            // 'i18n' => []
        ],
    ],
    'params'              => $params,
];
```

Everything else is in common/config/main.php, and the backend of the site is working perfectly, so I doubt that the problem is there.

Comment: Seems like the problem with your application config. Could you post it?

Comment: This is all there is in frontend/config/main.php:

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your project by running `composer update` or `php composer.phar update`. Sometimes the files get messed up while working on the `localhost`. It has happened to me a lot of times. But updating the packages solved my problem. See, if it works for you too.

Comment: Well, running `composer update` didn't help, although that has helped some times in the past. I just tried rebuilding `config/main.php`, and that did the trick. Both of those were excellent suggestions, but they don't really address my original question. Much has been made of using the stack trace to diagnose problems in Yii2, yet I have almost never, ever found it to be useful at all. Am I missing something, or is it truly just a lot of useless *gobbledygook*? It seems like the Yii developers could have given us more useful information when the framework fails.